# Concatenation in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, group-by, concatenation

I have a table (`l.loandeterminationscore`) that returns a result consisting of 3 #'s (XXX). I am using the below query to separate that result into a `LowRange` and a `HighRange` so that I may group the results returned into one result "XXX-XXX".

```
SELECT 
    l.LoanNumber,
    l.LoanDeterminationScore 'FICO', 
    FLOOR (l.LoanDeterminationScore / 20) * 20 AS LowRange,
    FLOOR (l.loanDeterminationScore / 20) * 20 + 19 AS HighRange
FROM 
    loan.LoanQA l
WHERE
    l.FundedDate = '10/15/2013'
```

The results returned from the above are something like this:

```
LoanNumber FICO LowRange HighRange
-----------------------------------
592301428  604  600      619
220300002  640  640      659
414805244  675  660      679
```

I'm trying to group the above `FICO` into a 20pt Range with the `LowRange` and `HighRange`. So in short, rather than having the two columns for the `LowRange` and `HighRange` I'd like it to return as one column showing the range as "600-619", "640-659", "660-679".

I've tried to `CONCAT` expression but I continually receive a "Syntax" error.

Comment: What **version** of SQL Server?? `CONCAT` is a new command in SQL Server **2012**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try this:

```
SELECT 
    l.LoanNumber,
    l.LoanDeterminationScore 'FICO', 
    CAST(FLOOR (l.LoanDeterminationScore / 20) * 20 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '-' +
    CAST(FLOOR (l.loanDeterminationScore / 20) * 20 + 19 AS VARCHAR(10)) AS 'Range' 
FROM 
    loan.LoanQA l
WHERE
    l.FundedDate = '10/15/2013'
```

Just `CAST` the numeric values to a string type, concatenate with `+`, and you're done!